# jquery data list is not passing into the html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am reading a JSON file and getting the values for `type`. I want to pass it as a list to the HTML element `#myList` yet what I get is `[object object]` in place of the list. However my `console.log` is showing exactly what I want, which is stored in `o.type`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(obj) {
        $('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function(o) {
            console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append('<li>' + obj + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Could somebody help to fix this?

Comment: What do you expect `.append('<li>' + obj + '</li>')` to do? Right now, it's coercing `obj` to a string, which with objects that don't provide a different `toString` method results in `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While concatenating an object with a string which concatenates `[object object]` to the string since `toString(obj)` result  `[object object]` .

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate the HTML code and append to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(obj) {
        $('#myList').data('types', obj.types.map(function(o) {
            console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append(obj.types.map(function(o) {
            return '<li>' + o.type + '</li>';
        }).join(''));
    });
});
```